# Thread loop, closing it in an Optimal way

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

Okay well, here is the code:

```
    private void Receivev2()
    { 
        try
        {
            using (UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient(1500))
            {
                while (connect == true)
                {

                    byte[] byteData = udpclient.Receive(ref remoteEP);
                    waveProvider.AddSamples(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
                    if (Record == true)
                    {
                        waveWriter.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VoiceChat-Receive ()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

It´s on a Thread, and well, it receives data from udp and plays it, nothing weird.

My problem however, is to make it stop normally, or well, don´t know how to put it.

But let´s say, i start the thread and it loops.
Then if i close my application, the application won´t "close", as the thread isn´t closing.

Now to solve that, i use IsBackground = true.

But i am not sure if that is an optimal way to do it, it feels like it will just force it to shut down, like ProcessKill or something.

Maybe it is the correct way, i don´t know.

Please give me advice on this.

Comment: do you have the handle of the thread that is running and playing? if yes call the thread.abort method. If not keep the handle and use it to close itself.

Comment: You are closing the application.  You set 'IsBackground = true' and the app closes OK, yes?  If so, how much more optimal could you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is call `UdpClient.Close`. This will cancel any pending operations and "poke" the `Receive` method into throwing a `SocketException` if it is blocking. Obviously, you will have to call `Close` from another thread which means you will need to refactor your code a bit so that `udpclient` is no longer a local variable. You will also need to set `connect` to false so that the loop ends.

So to summarize the steps are as follows.

- Call `Close` to prevent `Receive` from blocking.
- Set `connect` to false.
- Refactor your code to make the above possible.

Comment: I have done that before, but as you say, i get a SocketException "WSACancelBlockingCall", and well, i don´t want exceptions;S

Comment: Or should i take the exception as an "OK" and do like this:
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is SocketException)
                {                    
                    return;
                }
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VoiceChat-Receive ()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
            }

Comment: @user2587718: The exception is okay. This is how everyone else is handling this situation. So yeah, just catch exception.

Comment: Great, thanks, cause i thought, Exception = bad. But good to know this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a import thread, you'd better not set IsBackground ， because the main thread stop,It will be forced stop

stop thread step:

1 set connect=false  ,than main thread sleep a while untill it stop
2 if the thread still alive, you can abort it ,this step is not necessary
3 than join the back thread to main thread

just like this:

```
        connect= false;

        Thread.Sleep(200);
        if (thread1 != null)
        {
            if (thread1 .IsAlive)
            {
                thread1 .Abort();
                thread1 .Join();
            }
        }
```

Comment: 'ecause the main thread stop,It will be forced stop' - how is that bad?